# Can someone help me to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

`Solve[beta* 
phi *((1 + (1 - m)*alpha*theta ((phi^(-0.5) - 1)/((1 - theta)*phi^(-0.5) + theta)))) - 
delta == 0, phi]`

I run it and get nothing showing as results. Thanks so much for your help!!!
Appreciated!

Comment: Use `Solve` (not `solve`)?

Comment: Also, use `-1/2` instead of `-0.5` in the exponent to allow for exact solving.

Comment: This is a 3rd-order equation. In general, such equations cannot be solved in a simple form. However, a nice solution might exist if you set some parameters to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The most compact way of writing these solutions would be as squares of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects:

```
{Root[#^2*β-δ+(#-1)*(#^2*(1+(m-1)*α)*β-δ)*θ &, 1]^2,
 Root[#^2*β-δ+(#-1)*(#^2*(1+(m-1)*α)*β-δ)*θ &, 2]^2,
 Root[#^2*β-δ+(#-1)*(#^2*(1+(m-1)*α)*β-δ)*θ &, 3]^2}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the Mathematica syntax for what you show above is:

`Solve[\[Beta] \[Phi] ((1 + (1 - m) \[Alpha] \[Theta] ((\[Phi]^(-1/2) - 
 1)/((1 - \[Theta]) \[Phi]^(-1/2) + \[Theta])))) - \[Delta] == 0, \[Phi]]`

While this does give solutions, they are not pretty and quite complex. But you might be able to work with them.